# Display data in javascrip Notification function from Controller (Laravel)

Tags: javascript, laravel, notifications

I use Notification feature with javascript and i wanted to display data from Controller in the notification

this is my javascript with the error return

```
function notifyMe() {

           function AutoRefresh( t ) {
               setTimeout("location.reload(true);", t);
            }
        // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
        if (!("Notification" in window)) {
            alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
        }

        // Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
        else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {

            var notification = new Notification({{ $postnotif->title }});
        }

        else if (Notification.permission !== "denied") {
            Notification.requestPermission().then(function (permission) {
            if (permission === "granted") {
            var notification = new Notification({{ $postnotif->title }});
            }
            });
        }

        }
       </script>
```

it returns this error [error return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXabk.png)

this is my logic in controller

```
$postnotif = DB::table('post_contents')->where('created_at', '=', '2019-03-11 20:07:49')->first();
```

this is the json from $postnotif

```
{#1287
  +"id": 1
  +"post_id": 1
  +"lang": "id"
  +"slug": "beranda"
  +"title": "Beranda"
  +"body": "<p>Website Resmi FIFGROUP, member of ASTRA Perusahaan Pembiayaan Terpercaya di Indonesia.</p>"
  +"excerpt": null
  +"image": null
  +"tag": "astra, pembiayaan, terpercaya, indonesia, cicilan, kredit, pembiayaan motor bekas, pembiayaan motor baru, pembiayaan multiguna, pembiayaan umrah, dana kuliah, m "
  +"metas": "a:1:{s:4:"file";N;}"
  +"created_at": "2019-03-11 20:07:49"
  +"updated_at": "2019-08-30 00:40:47"
}
```

how to declare correctly from controller to javascript?

Comment: You are trying to access `Beranda` which is not defined on your project.

Comment: i'm trying to access the "title" variable which return "beranda", but it said beranda is not defined.

Comment: comment out this line `var notification = new Notification({{ $postnotif->title }});` and print the `$postnotif` object. `console.log('{{$postnotif}}');` then see the output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must access the laravel variable in the following way:

```
     var notification = new Notification({!! $postnotif->title !!});
```

Comment: yes thankyou! adding to this, it should be with qoutes. it should be like var notification = new Notification( '{!! $postnotif->title !!}' );